# transmission blown?

Tags: transmission, mercury

while i was driving my car going about 20 miles an hour i tried to stop and all my brakes were gone even my e brake...i panicked shut my key and put my car in park..well it stopped but it made a boom sound....i had the brakes fixed the next day and the car was fine....yesterday i went up to the store and when i came out the car wouldn't go into drive or reverse....it has transmission fluid in it.....did my transmission blow...there is no leak either.....i need to know asap because i'm going to have to junk it and if the transmission isn't blown and it's just something easy to fix i'd rather do that..

Comment: What is the year/model/miles of the Mercury?

Comment: Are you able to move the selector stick?

Answer (score 3):

The parking pawl is designed to shear; that piece might be floating around and causing trouble.    The parking pawl system is also designed to ratchet until the output drum external teeth slow enough to engage.

While it's not good practice to shift into park while moving, I am not ready to *doomspeak* your transmission as *blown*, or even needing an overhaul.  Honest focused repair, yes.  Complete overhaul or replacement?  No way.

Another possibility is that in your haste to get it into park, the manual valve or more importantly the selector levers/linkage are bent or out of adjustment so that the "gears" are no longer aligned with the shifter detents.

However, unfortunately transmission repair is quite specialized, and is liable to be expensive regardless of the extent of damage.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when things make a boom sound they are not happy campers. Jamming it into park at 20 mph would definitely damage or destroy quite a few things in the transmission. Is your transmission blown? - Yes

2 options available:

```
  Major overhaul on the transmission. 
  Replace the transmission
```

Replacing the transmission would probably be cheaper. Check with the mechanic who did your brakes.